# How to merge result in shellscript

Tags: linux, shell

I want to merge results in shellscript.

```
ls -lrt
-rw-r--r--  1 cu  staff  11 Jul 23 23:57 aaa
-rw-r--r--  1 cu  staff   8 Jul 24 00:12 bbb
-rw-r--r--  1 cu  staff  33 Jul 24 02:31 ccc
-rw-r--r--  1 cu  staff  75 Jul 24 02:32 ddd

cksum `ls`
1108326690 11 aaa
1221844548 8 bbb
1213522119 33 ccc
3248460215 75 ddd

↓

-rw-r--r--  1 cu  staff  11 Jul 23 23:57 aaa　1108326690 11 aaa
-rw-r--r--  1 cu  staff   8 Jul 24 00:12 bbb　1221844548 8 bbb
-rw-r--r--  1 cu  staff  33 Jul 24 02:31 ccc　1213522119 33 ccc
-rw-r--r--  1 cu  staff  75 Jul 24 02:32 ddd　3248460215 75 ddd
```

I tried the command below but failed.
(ls -l; cksum `ls`) | xargs

Please show me kindly how to merge these results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you want:

```
paste  <(ls -lrt *) <(cksum `ls -rt`)
```

Note that this is intended to be used interactively (not inside a script) and may not work properly if filenames contain "weird" characters, or the current directory has subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `{ ls -lrt ; cksum ls ; } > outfile.txt` first.
Then, maybe read the contents from the `outfile.txt` using `cat outfile.txt`.

Or, do it all in one go with `{ ls -lrt ; cksum ls ; } > outfile.txt | cat`

As to why `(ls -l; cksum ls) | xargs` didn't work, referring to [j9s's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176929) :

> Code:
>
> ( command1 ; command2 ; command3 ) | cat
>
> { command1 ; command2 ; command3 ; } > outfile.txt
>
> The main difference between the two is that the first one splits of a
> child process, while the second one operates in the context of the
> main shell. This can have consequences regarding the setting and use
> of variables and other environment settings, as well as performance.